# On the big $O$ notation asymptotics

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

If $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a function and $$-\Im(f(x+iy))=\mathcal{O}(y)$$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the big O notation,
then prove that $$\Im(f(x+iy))=\mathcal{O}(y) \ \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ \ y\to \infty$$

I tried: Since $$-\Im(f(x+iy))=\mathcal{O}(y) 
 \ \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ \ y\to \infty   $$ so there exists $M,y_0$ such that $$|\Im(f(x+iy))|\leq M y $$ whenever $y\geq y_0$.

So can we say from the above that $$\Im(f(x+iy))=\mathcal{O}(y)  \ \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ \ y\to \infty  $$

Do we require the limit definition of big O?

Comment: Whan you say $O$, you should have an "as" clause to go with it.   Perhaps "as $y \to 0^+$".

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. I have included that in the question. Please answer

Comment: There is a lot of fluff here you can abstract away. Really, all you have is $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $g\in\mathcal{O}(y)$ implies $-g\in\mathcal{O}(y)$

Comment: @FShrike Thanks. But my $f$ is not a real valued function. What you said, will it hold for complex function?

Comment: @Jiya It will. But, the imaginary part *is* a real function

Comment: @FShrike Thanks a lot